# Transform of a wave equation to a hyperbolic system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations

We consider the wave equation $$y_{tt}=y_{xx}+a(t,x)y, \text{ x$\in$(0,1)}, t\in (0,\infty).$$
with Dirichlet boundary conditions.
I want to transform this equation to a hyperbolic system of the form 
$$z_t=Az_x+Bz.$$
So, I introduced the following substitutions: $z^1=y_t$, $z^2=y_x$, I obtained
$$z^1_t=z^2_{x}+az^1+a_ty$$
$$z^2_t=z^1_{x}$$

**The question here:**
How I get rid of the $y$ in the $z^1$ formula? Is there more adequate substitution then this ? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include $y$ in your $z$ vector.  Set $z^1 =y, z^2 = y_t, z^3 = y_x$.  Then 
$$
\partial_t 
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\ y_t \\ y_x
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
y_t \\ y_{xx} + a y \\ y_{xt}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\partial_x
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\ y_t \\ y_x
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1& 0\\
a & 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y \\ y_t \\ y_x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is the form you want.

Comment: Thank you @Glitch for replaying. Is there any alternative substitutions to write the above system under a $2 \times 2$ hyperbolic system with $A$ is diagonal matrix? I h'ave tried but I have not secceeded.

Comment: @Gustave You're welcome.  I don't think it's possible to reduce to a $2 \times 2$ first-order system when you have the lower order term $a y$ in your original equation.  If you want to capture the PDE then $z$ must contain both $y_t$ and $y_x$, but $y$ itself cannot be obtained from these without integration.  If you wanted to integrate, then you could obtain $y$, but you would break the structure of the first-order PDE system.  Is there a particular reason you don't like the $3 \times 3$ system?  The tricks to solve a $2\times 2$ should work here just as well...

Comment: Thank you sir..